# Por que alguns comandos "git" são precedidos por um traço e outros por dois traços?

Tags: git

Estou a aprender a utilizar o *git* e notei que certos parâmetros são precedidos por um traço enquanto outros são precedidos por dois.

Exemplo:

```
git branch --merged
git branch -d nome
```

Qual a razão?

Comment: @Rinzler Se desse para dar downvote em comentários, eu dava. Svn é, no mínimo, arcaico. E sugerir usar um sistema arcaico porque a maior parte dos comandos tem 2 versões (full e shorthand) é um péssimo conselho.

Comment: @dcastro downvote não tem como, mas tem como sinalizar como desnecessário

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como dá para perceber no seu exemplo existe uma diferença entre eles. Com apenas um traço é a forma abreviada de um comando enquanto com dois traços é o comando "por extenso".

É comum existirem as duas formas para a maioria dos comandos.

Isto segue o padrão adotado pelo Unix na sua origem. Inicialmente existiam apenas opções com um traço e uma letra, assim simplificava o *parse* e dava agilidade para usar.

Com o tempo tornou-se necessário ter mais opções e começou se dar mais valor para que ficasse mais legível o que está fazendo e simplificações não eram tão desejáveis. Então se adotou o padrão por extenso e para diferenciar houve a preferência pelos dois traços.

O Git segue totalmente a filosofia do Unix/Linux (afinal seu principal criador também é o criador do Linux). Hoje não existe uma razão especial a não ser manter o padrão já estabelecido e evitar confusão.

Isso é usado no que normalmente se chama de *option* ou *switch*.

[Fonte](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma outra razão que encontrei, talvez a principal, é permitir distinguir uma opção, constituída por vários caracteres, de uma sequência de opções. Se `merged` fosse escrita com um traço seria interpretada como `-m-e-r-g-e-d`. Um exemplo disso é o comando `git commit -am "blabla"` que executa o `add` e atribui uma mensagem ao *commit*.

Comment: É um dos motivos da diferenciação que eu falei.

Answer (score 11):

Quando você utiliza com um traço está provavelmente utilizando uma versão *shortcut* do comando, por exemplo, vários programas tem o comando `help`, que você pode acessar

```
nome_do_programa --help
```

ou

```
nome_do_programa -h
```

Em `git branch -d nome_do_branch`, o `-d` é o *shortcut* de `--delete`, por exemplo:

```
git branch --delete nome_do_branch
```